# Change background color of adjacent buttons in Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, uistackview

I want to change colors of all **adjacent** buttons in my *UIStackView* when **any** button is pressed. In the end I will turn this into an animation - almost like a ripple effect.

I looked at the *Combine Framework* but that seems to have too many unrelated features for what I need. Because the user could press any button, I don't think creating an observer for every button is an economical solution. I was hoping there was a way to find the adjacent view of a button's properties and influence that in some way?

Is there a simple solution to this problem, or do I need to build a complex matrix of *IF statements*, which is what I'm prepared to do in any case.

All my buttons are in a *UIStackView* (8 horizontal stack-views in 1 x vertical stack-view)

Here follows my non-ideal solution:

```
if sender.tag == 1 then {
    view1.layer.backgroundColor = blue
    view2.layer.backgroundColor = blue
    view3.layer.backgroundColor = blue
} else if sender.tag == 2 then {
    view4.layer.backgroundColor = blue
    view5.layer.backgroundColor = blue
    view6.layer.backgroundColor = blue
}...
```

Comment: How are you defining "adjacent" here? In other words, why does tag #1 result in 1, 2, 3, and tag #2 is 4,5,6? What's the formula?

Comment: Adjacent in the UIStackView, sorry I will make that a bit clearer.

Comment: Do you *know* what order they are in or do you have to determine adjacency by comparing the coordinates?

Comment: The short answer, only because of how I arranged them in IB. I guess THAT is the crux of my question, how do I determine which buttons are adjacent to the one the user pressed.

Comment: Okay -- I've removed my answer, then, as it doesn't seem relevant. It seems like the prudent thing would be to assign them in a logical way so that you *know* which are adjacent unless you're moving them around programmatically later.

Answer (score 0):

You can find "adjacent" buttons by searching a 2-D array.

For example... if you have an 8x8 "grid" of buttons, you'll have 8 "rows" of 8 "columns". When you tap any button, search through the rows to find the row and column of the tapped button.

Suppose you find it at `Row 4 : Col 4`, then to find the adjacent buttons subtract and add a row and column in each direction:

```
// arrays are Zero based
// if tapped button is at 
array[3][3]
// the button above it is at
array[3 - 1][3]
// the button to the left it is at
array[3][3 - 1]
// the button to the right it is at
array[3][3 + 1]
// the button below it is at
array[3 + 1][3]
```

[image]

If by adjacent you also want to include diagonals, you just need another set of "+/-" for "above and to the left" / "above and to the right" / "below and to the left" / "below and to the right":

[image]

Here's a complete example (code only... no `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // 2-D array to track the buttons
    //  we could use the stack views and their arrangedSubviews, but
    //  this will avoid repeated unwrapping of optionals
    
    var arrayOfButtons: [[UIButton]] = []
    
    // add a reset button above the grid
    let resetBtn = UIButton()

    // add a segmented control to select fully adjacent or diagonal
    let segCtrl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Full Only", "Include Diagonal"])

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create an 8x8 "grid" of buttons
        
        let outerStack = UIStackView()
        outerStack.axis = .vertical
        outerStack.distribution = .fillEqually

        // we'll use Row:Col for the button labels
        for row in 0..<8 {
            var thisRow: [UIButton] = []
            let rowStack = UIStackView()
            rowStack.distribution = .fillEqually
            for col in 0..<8 {
                let b = UIButton()
                b.backgroundColor = .blue
                b.setTitle("\(row):\(col)", for: [])
                b.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
                b.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .highlighted)
                // add a border so we can see the frames
                b.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
                b.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
                // square buttons
                b.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: b.widthAnchor).isActive = true
                // add button to rowStack
                rowStack.addArrangedSubview(b)
                // add button to 2-D array
                thisRow.append(b)
                // add target for button
                b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            }
            // add rowStack to outerStack
            outerStack.addArrangedSubview(rowStack)
            // add this row of buttons to 2-D array
            arrayOfButtons.append(thisRow)
        }

        // outerStack properties
        outerStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(outerStack)
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain outerStack width
            outerStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            outerStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            
            // center vertically
            outerStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),

        ])
        
        resetBtn.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        resetBtn.setTitle("Reset", for: [])
        resetBtn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        resetBtn.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .highlighted)
        resetBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(resetTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        [resetBtn, segCtrl].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            resetBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerStack.topAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            resetBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerStack.leadingAnchor),
            resetBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerStack.trailingAnchor),
            
            segCtrl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerStack.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            segCtrl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerStack.leadingAnchor),
            segCtrl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerStack.trailingAnchor),

        ])

        segCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    }
    
    @objc func resetTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        arrayOfButtons.forEach { thisRow in
            thisRow.forEach { btn in
                btn.backgroundColor = .blue
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func btnTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        guard let tappedBtn = sender as? UIButton else {
            return
        }
        
        // find the row and column for the tapped button
        var row: Int = -1
        var col: Int = -1
        
        for r in 0..<arrayOfButtons.count {
            let thisRow = arrayOfButtons[r]
            if let c = thisRow.firstIndex(of: tappedBtn) {
                // found the tapped button
                row = r
                col = c
                break
            }
        }
        
        if row == -1 || col == -1 {
            // did not find the tapped button in the grid!!!
            return
        }
        
        // we found the row:col of the tapped button
        var adjacentButtons: [UIButton] = [
            tappedBtn
        ]
        
        if segCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            
            // adjacent means ONLY above, left, right, below
            if row > 0 {
                // get button above
                adjacentButtons.append(arrayOfButtons[row - 1][col])
            }
            if col > 0 {
                // get button to the left
                adjacentButtons.append(arrayOfButtons[row][col - 1])
            }
            if row < arrayOfButtons.count - 1 {
                // get button below
                adjacentButtons.append(arrayOfButtons[row + 1][col])
            }
            if col < arrayOfButtons[row].count - 1 {
                // get button to the right
                adjacentButtons.append(arrayOfButtons[row][col + 1])
            }
            
        } else {

            // adjacent includes diagonals
            if row > 0 {
                
                // get button above and to the left
                if col > 0 {
                    adjacentButtons.append(arrayOfButtons[row - 1][col - 1])
                }
                
                // get button above
                adjacentButtons.append(arrayOfButtons[row - 1][col])
                
                // get button above and to the right
                if col < arrayOfButtons[row].count - 1 {
                    adjacentButtons.append(arrayOfButtons[row - 1][col + 1])
                }
                
            }
            
            if col > 0 {
                // get button to the left
                adjacentButtons.append(arrayOfButtons[row][col - 1])
            }
        
            if col < arrayOfButtons[row].count - 1 {
                // get button to the right
                adjacentButtons.append(arrayOfButtons[row][col + 1])
            }
            
            if row < arrayOfButtons.count - 1 {
                
                // get button below and to the left
                if col > 0 {
                    adjacentButtons.append(arrayOfButtons[row + 1][col - 1])
                }
                
                // get button below
                adjacentButtons.append(arrayOfButtons[row + 1][col])
                
                // get button below and to the right
                if col < arrayOfButtons[row].count - 1 {
                    adjacentButtons.append(arrayOfButtons[row + 1][col + 1])
                }
                
            }
    
        }
        
        adjacentButtons.forEach { btn in
            btn.backgroundColor = .red
        }

    }
    
}
```